# Python str not list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to obtain array of int like `[1,2,3]`

 but got `[dict_values([1]),dict_values([2]),dict_values([3])]`

My code:

```
taken_employee_ids_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
taken_employee_ids = [str(taken_employee_ids_list.values()) for taken_employee_ids_list in taken_employee_ids_dict]

in_values_check = ','.join(str(id) for id in taken_employee_ids)
```

And then in_values_check should go in:

```
qry = "SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ',', surname) AS full_name, id \
            FROM employees \
            WHERE date_terminated IS NULL \
            and id NOT IN " + "(" + in_values_check + ")" \
            " ORDER BY first_name, surname ASC"
```

sorry i am new to python thanks

Comment: Can you please post what `taken_employee_ids_dict` looks like?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], it's actually required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **lambda** or **list comprehension**

**With Lambda,**

```
taken_employee_ids_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
in_values_check = list(map(lambda x : x['id'], taken_employee_ids_dict))
print(in_values_check)
```

**With List Comprehension**,

```
taken_employee_ids_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
in_values_check = [dic['id'] for dic in taken_employee_ids_dict]
print(in_values_check)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `taken_employee_ids = list(map(lambda x : x['id'], taken_employee_ids_dict))

in_values_check = ','.join(str(id) for id in taken_employee_ids)`

Comment: @JasonPolydor best of luck :)

Answer (score 3):

For a problem like this, a list comprehension is a commonly applied solution:

```
taken_employee_ids_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
in_values_check = [employee["id"] for employee in taken_employee_ids_dict]
print(in_values_check)
```

This outputs

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
taken_employee_ids = [str(employee["id"]) for employee in taken_employee_ids_dict]

in_values_check = ','.join(str(id) for id in taken_employee_ids)
```

Comment: not working i got AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'. between i am using python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
taken_employee_ids_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
final_list = []
for ele in taken_employee_ids_dict:
  for key,value in ele.items():
    final_list.append(value)
print(final_list)
```